# how to change category filter position in magento 2 layered navigation?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, filter, position

I have to move category filter after my custom attribute filter but I am not able to how to move it please help me how to change position. I want to move category filter in the last position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filters in the layered navigation are being build in this file:

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer/FilterList.php

```
    /**
 * Retrieve list of filters
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer
 * @return array|Filter\AbstractFilter[]
 */
public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
{
    if (!count($this->filters)) {
        $this->filters = [
            $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
        ];
        foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
            $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
        }
    }
    return $this->filters;
}
```

The result of `$this->filters` will look like

```
$this->filters[0] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category
$this->filters[1] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
$this->filters[2] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
$this->filters[3] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
$this->filters[4] = Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute
```

With a custom plugin `afterGetFilters` you should be able to check if the first item in the array is instanceof `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category`. If so, place it at the end of the array before returning the result.

Comment: Hello I want to move category filter on 2 position after color, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

work for me

```
public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
    {
        if (!count($this->filters)) {
            $this->filters = [
                $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
            ];
            foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
                $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
            }
        }
        $data = array_shift($this->filters);
        $this->filters[]=  $data;
        return $this->filters;
    }
```

Comment: Hello I want to move category filter on 2 position after color, how can I achieve this?